# How to properly debug a UWP backgroud task with no execution time limits?

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2022

I wrote a UWP backgroud task and I add to the UWP app manifest the restricted capability `extendedBackgroundTaskTime` to remove execution time limit.

When I debug the code, the background task was however limited in execution time.

My environment:

- OS: Windows 11 (23H2): Build 22631
- WinUI 3 - Windows App SDK 1.5.0: 1.5.240227000
- Visual studio 2022

Documentations:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-in-the-background-indefinetly

Example code: https://github.com/jhonToni/Winui3BackgroudWorkerBug

How to properly debug a UWP backgroud task with no execution time limits ?

Comment: Could you please provide a [example] to help us further check the problem for you?

Comment: I added example code to question

Comment: Your main project is a winui3 project, use C#/WinRT NuGet package to create Windows runtime types and components to implement out-of-process background task. Sorry, currently Winui3 does not support unlimited background task. It is recommended to submit a feature request on [GitHub Issues](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues).

Comment: Winui3 supports "extendedBackgroundTaskTime" capability, but the package needs to be sent to Microsoft for approval process.

Comment: It seems that my information has fallen behind. Could you please tell me where is the explanation that Winui3 supports extendedBackgroundTaskTime.

Comment: See Documentation link in the question.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-in-the-background-indefinetly This is the UWP document, it is supported in the UWP project, but WinUI3 and UWP are different. 'extendedBackgroundTaskTime' unlimited background task is not supported in WinUI3 for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

Your main project is a WinUI3 project, you use C#/WinRT NuGet package to create Windows runtime types and components to [implement out-of-process background task](https://Create%20and%20register%20an%20out-of-process%20background%20task). This applies for apps using the Windows App SDK, WinUI 3, WPF, or WinForms. But that doesn't mean that `extendedBackgroundTaskTime` can be used in Winui3 to remove the background limits.

`extendedBackgroundTaskTime` unlimited background task is not supported in WinUI3 for the time being.
It is recommended to submit a feature request on [GitHub Issues](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues).